# Where can I find official depictions of the written alphabets/scripts of the various languages of D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, languages

To add more flavor, I want to create documents written in the actual script.

I remember awhile back seeing examples of the Common/Elven/Dwarven alphabets for instance, but can not recall where I can find those.

Is there a place online where these alphabets are available, the ones that at one point I remember seeing in official WoTC books?

As a side question, were these alphabets copyrighted by WoTC, or did they take them from real-world sources? If so, which book can they be found in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Likely you are recalling the alphabet used for various races in Forgotten Realms. In general you want to use the (alphabet name) followed by truetype in google to find fonts for these alphabets.

For Forgotten Realms you want to [look here](http://www.candlekeep.com/library/treasures.htm#fonts) at the Candlekeep website.

For Middle Earth you want to search on Quenya, Cirth, Tengwar. I prefer using Tengwar as the vowels are accents on the consonants which give a true unearthly feel to the writing.

As for copyright, the font files can be copyrighted but there are many free version out there. Copyright on the alphabet itself is a grey area. For commercial work I would come up with your own or search or buy a fantasy font that is open for commercial use.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of. Thorass and Dethek will work.

Comment: Unearthly feel from diacritical vowels?  You mean like Arabic?  Or Hebrew?

Comment: Sindarin puts the diacritic mark on the consonant that comes after the vowel. That's kind of weird.

Comment: I'm not seeing how shifting the position of a vowel diacritic by one space makes things unearthly.

Answer (score 10):

In 5th edition D&D, scripts for Elvish, Dwarven, and Draconic can be found on the bottoms of pages 123, 124, and 125 of the *Player's Handbook*. There is no given script for Common, though.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I think Common is assumed to be English, or whatever real-world language you're using (i.e. the top row of the illustrations you reference is meant to be the Common script).

Answer (score 8):

http://Omniglot.com hosts a comparison of literally dozens of scripts, including the Tolkienian ones.

You'll especially want to look through the con-scripts section; scripts for conlangs (constructed languages) and alternate scripts for English.

Plus the site has most of the currently used real-world scripts.

Also has links to fonts for many, and entry mode kits for a few, for making use of them.

Answer (score 5):

You may be thinking of the alphabets in one of the Forgotten Realms campaign guides. For example, page 86 of the D&D 3rd edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* has the Dethek, Espruar, and Thorass (dwarven, elvish, and ancient common) alphabets written out. Earlier editions of the campaign setting had those alphabets too, and it's likely that the 4th edition guide does as well though I haven't read it. Of note is that the Espruar alphabet was redesigned for 3rd edition, so the earlier version of Espruar (from the FR campaign setting for AD&D 2nd edition and earlier) has a very different character from the later version.

These alphabets are almost certainly copyrighted by Wizards of the Coast, since they were developed either in-house or under work-for-hire by TSR. The Dethek alphabet does appear to be inspired, by but not taken directly from, the Norse [runic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_alphabet). I don't recognise the inspirations for Espruar or Thorass, if there were any.

Despite the copyright, I know that there are Dethek, Espruar, and Thorass font files floating about online somewhere. I couldn't point you to them, but I know they exist because I've found copies of them before.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the written-language scripts for D&D 4.0 can be found in PHB1 and the Essentials Rules Compendium.